# Codeigniter URL rewrite to hide controler and method name

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing

My current url is universitytwig.com/user/userprofile/cm.cm , where user is the controller , userprofile is the method and cm.cm is the parameter .How i change this url to universitytwig.com/cm.cm by route.php or by routing from database, Or by .htaccess

Answer (score 2):

Try to add

```
$route['cm.cm'] = 'user/userprofile/cm.cm';
```

to your application/config/routes.php

Or

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'user/userprofile/$1';
```

if your parameter can be different.

Comment: +1 for the first approach if params are hardcoded but second solution is not good  you cannot use other controllers

Comment: You are right. This was a fast solution.
Second solution will work if all other controllers will be predefined before `$route['(:any)']`

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `routes.php` but if you make a rule in something like cm.cm to `user/userprofile/cm.cm`

```
$route['(:any)']= 'user/userprofile/$1';
```

But this is not a perfect solution it will point all the controllers of every thing after base url to `user/userprofile/` you need to specify some string the `CI routes` will identify that this needs to be point on this controller **if cm.cm is dynamic parameters not hard coded** for this your url structure should be

```
universitytwig.com/students/cm.cm
```

and in routes you can now make a rule

```
$route['students/(:any)']= 'user/userprofile/$1';
```

This will work for your scenario